# Abstract algebra question: abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

$H=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} : b \in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

$G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d\end{pmatrix}: a, b, d \in\mathbb{R}, ad\ne0\right\}$

$H$ is normal subgroup of $G$. Show that $G/H$ is abelian.

Comment: Can you add some of your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: There is a proposition which says that if G is abelian then G/H is abelian but if G/H is abelian does not imply that G is ableian.My teacher told me that show that G is ablelian then it will imply G/H is abelian. Abelian means commutative but as we know matrices are not commutative.So how can we show that G/H is ableian.

Comment: Hint: It is even possible to show that $H$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ (with respect to inclusion) with the property that $G/H$ is Abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Verifying that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ only requires showing that the relevant properties hold:

1. $1\in H$ (what's $1$ in this case?)
2. if $x,y\in H$, then $xy\in H$ (do the multiplication)
3. if $x\in H$, then $x^{-1}\in H$ (note that $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & b\\0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)^{-1}=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & -b\\0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$)

In order to show that $H$ is normal in $G$, what's the condition to verify? Note that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d\end{pmatrix}^{\!-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}d^{-1} & -b \\ 0 & a^{-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that you can easily do the required computation.

Hint for $G/H$ abelian: the map $\varphi\colon G\to (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})\times(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ defined by
$$
\varphi\colon\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & d\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto(a,d)
$$
is a homomorphism, when the codomain is considered as a group under coordinatewise multiplication.

Comment: The last hint is a subtle one, but a good one.

Comment: @DanielRust I believe that dissociating groups from homomorphisms is wrong. Studying a quotient group usually *is* finding the right homomorphism.

Comment: Totally agree. The first isomorphism theorem is universal. This is also very true for linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,x'\in G$ with
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix},\:\:\:
x'=\begin{bmatrix}
a' & b' \\
0 & d'
\end{bmatrix}$$

Note that
$\overline{x}\overline{x'}=\overline{xx'}=\overline{\begin{bmatrix}
aa' & ab'+bd' \\
0 & dd'
\end{bmatrix}}$ and 
$\overline{x'}\overline{x}=\overline{x'x}=\overline{\begin{bmatrix}
aa' & a'b+b'd \\
0 & dd'
\end{bmatrix}}$ so it remains to find some element $h\in H$ such that $$\begin{bmatrix}
aa' & ab'+bd' \\
0 & dd'
\end{bmatrix}h=\begin{bmatrix}
aa' & ab'+bd' \\
0 & dd'
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & s \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
aa' & a'b+b'd \\
0 & dd'
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Can you find such an $s\in\mathbb{R}$. Remember that $ad\neq 0$ and $a'd'\neq 0$ so when dividing through by something, check that it's non-zero using these criteria.